# Why is a line displayed between these buttons?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

How remove this line beetween buttons? First time I have this situation. Please look at my code here:

```
    <a href="#info-section">
      <button class="cta-btn rg">WATCH</button>
    </a>  
    <a href="#info-section">
      <button class="cta-btn lf">LEARN MORE</button>
    </a>
```

[image]

My CSS responsive for buttons:

```
.cta-btn{
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
  &:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
.rg {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.lf{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Fix your broken HTML - you can not put `button` into `a` elements, that is invalid.

Comment: Jezus.... of corse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's to do with the way you have the `<a>` tags surrounding the `<button>` but changing it to `<a href="#info-section"><button class="cta-btn rg">WATCH</button></a>` removes the underline. It's almost as if there's a space character that it's formatting.

**Note, this isn't the correct way to do it, but it removes the underline.**

Answer (score 1):

I think that line is the underline of the A-tags. 
Try adding text-decoration: none; to your `<a>`. Like this:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

It could also be possible you forgot to close an A-tag before this part of your code. So check if every `<a>` has an closing `</a>`

Comment: @Jos You are correct, but the `text-decoration` needs removing from the `a`, not the `.cta-btn`

Comment: You are so right, my bad! Will edit this, however I think the solution is the one that 
CBroe mentions.